# Should we get rid of the name-that-claim tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

There is one question with the [name-that-claim](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name-that-claim) tag. I really don't think that is a useful tag at least in part because of the sort of question that it will encourage. I was about to remove it from the one question on which it has been employed and then noticed it is one of the few with a tag wiki entry. Thus, I backed off of unilateral action. What is the community's sense?

Answer (score 3):

**I don't like this tag.** It seems to me questions that could be meaningfully tagged with it are unlikely to be real philosophy questions.

Comment: My question identified a claim/quotation, and I am genuinely seeking the author/source of said claim. The claim is by a philosopher, read during my undergraduate study pursuing a Philosophy major. So how is that not related?

Comment: @mfg, it isn't a bad question -- it just may set a poor example, and I am worried it sends the wrong message to new users.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with [Joe's answer](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/should-we-get-rid-of-the-name-that-claim-tag/85#85), especially the part in bold.

However, I do think that some of the questions with this tag *could* be real philosophy questions. In fact, the particular question with that tag now isn't necessarily a bad question. But it's certainly obvious to me that establishing the tag is sending the wrong message.

Instead, you should tag the question with the type of philosophical thought that it seeks, not with the name of the game. It's another manifestation of the dreaded "meta tag", which I discuss more about [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/which-tags-should-we-be-using/74#74).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be removed: done.

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, **or generally what “kind” of question it is** (poll, how-to, etc.).